# How to update the database table in button click?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, ado.net

I am working on the MVC3 with ADO.Net Connectivity, an then i am updating the div with jQuery

Here i my code

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult GetData()
{
 return this.Json(_db.MYMOVIELISTs, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
public void Insert(string Id)
{
    var movieToInsert = new MYMOVIELIST { Title = "Ben", Director = "LEMe", ID = Id };
    // Save new movie to DB
    _db.AddToMYMOVIELISTs(movieToInsert);
    _db.SaveChanges();
}
```

**ClientSide**

```
function insertCallback(result) {
    readData();
}
function readData() {
    info.empty();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'Home/GetData',
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var panel = $("<div class='panel' ></div>")
                var d = data[i];
                panel.append("ID: " + d.ID + "</br>");
                panel.append("Title: " + d.Title + "</br>");
                panel.append("Director: " + d.Director + "</br>");
                panel.append("<hr>");
                panel.data("info", d);
                panel.appendTo(info);
            }
        }
    });
}
$("#btnAdd").click(function () {
    $.post("Home/Insert", $("form").serialize(), insertCallback);
});
```

This is works Fine, my problem is i want to update the Database table in "Save" buttom click. i tried to call the `_db.SaveChanges();` in save button click instead of the `Insert` it is not adding the `movieToInsert` to table, here i want to know is how to save the database later, Here any thing am doing wrong or is there any best approach for DB connectivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are serializing a form, so eventually you may want below... which will bind your serialized form to the a movie model/entity:

```
[AcceptVerbs("POST")]
public void Insert(MovieEntity movie)
```

As for database practice, I recommend reading about the repository pattern and dependency injection as it pertains to ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: without '[AcceptVerbs("POST")]' it is works fine. this is not the answer i want. i asked a question about save recored in table right?

Comment: thanks I edited my answer... as far as the question, are you using linq2sql, an ORM (like entity framework, nHibernate) Application Data Access Blocks, or is that a pure ADO.NET custom database class that you wrote?

Comment: I am using ADO.NET custom database class.